# Is it possible to check automatically if a PDF follows the PDF/UA standard?

Tags: pdf

There are different standards for PDF files:

- PDF/A: PDF/A-1a, PDF/A-2a or PDF/A-3a
- [PDF/UA](https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/TaggedPDFBestPracticeGuideSyntax.pdf)
- Potentially more

Is it possible to check if a given PDF file follows the PDF/UA standard?

Comment: As one can embed a PDF/A-1 inside a PDF/A-2, I think the question is a lot more complicated. AFAIK there is no simple way other than checking elements inside a PDF against a list of things allowed (e.g. transparent objects, compressed objects etc.)

Comment: Even the open source veraPDF tool (https://verapdf.org/) comes to unclear conclusions...

Comment: https://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-lab/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac.html?device=    works pretty well. It is freeware but not open source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially.

Most PDF based ISO standards (PDF/X, PDF/VT, PDF/E, PDF/VCR, PDF/A) can be automatically checked in software. I'm affiliated with a company (callas software) that has commercial software that handles all of these. The tool also has support for PDF/UA, but the verification is only partial.

The reason is subtle but important. All other PDF based ISO standards state that PDF files need to follow certain guidelines, and those guidelines are easy to verify in software. This or that property has to be set, that property can't have this value, this element must have that or that color space...

PDF/UA makes many of such claims as well, but it also makes different claims. Two examples:

- For a document to be compliant with PDF/UA, all text in the document *must* be tagged with the "correct" language.
- Similarly, the elements in the document must be tagged with their type (image, paragraph, title, footnote, table) "in a correct way".

The problem is not for software to check that language tags are present or that structure is present. The problem is for the software to verify that the language tags are indeed for the correct language. And that the structure in the document corresponds to what a human would think makes sense.

There are more examples like that in the PDF/UA standard, and they mean that while software can definitely assist in the verification process, it can't conclusively say that the file is correct. The best it can ever say is that it doesn't contradict one of the computer verifiable rules.

Comment: Is it possible with Python to check if a "table" tag is present?

Comment: It should be - structure in PDF is a tree-like data structure that lives in the PDF document; with a library that can access low-level PDF objects it should be easy to get to it and check whether any of the structural elements are for a table. Just remember that structure is optional in PDF and likely not there in random PDF files.

Comment: Do you happen to know a Python library which supports this? Or do I have to go to the PDF specs, understand the format, and write a PDF parser just to get table tags?

Comment: I have no knowledge of Python at all unfortunately. But I can tell you that going to the spec and writing this from scratch would be a quite big project that I personally would try to avoid if at all possible.